# What does BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou error (from Amazon S3) actually mean? I can't find any reason affecting me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backup, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 to back up my Rails app's mysql database. And I am using astrails-safe plugin to do that and I got the "Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it. (AWS::S3::BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou)" error back whenever I try to update it.

I have checked that the folder in which I am going to back up is there in my account already. It's just that I can't upload the files from the code (using astrails-safe).

ok. When I run this code

> sudo astrails-safe
>   /Users/pww/sites/web_apps/myapp/trunk/lib/backup/local.rb

, I got the following error.

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/error.rb:38:in `raise': Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it. (AWS::S3::BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou)
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:72:in `request'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:88:in `put'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/bucket.rb:79:in `create'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/lib/astrails/safe/s3.rb:29:in `save'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/lib/astrails/safe/s3.rb:28:in `save'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/lib/astrails/safe/sink.rb:8:in `process'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/lib/astrails/safe/backup.rb:15:in `run'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/lib/astrails/safe/backup.rb:12:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/lib/astrails/safe/backup.rb:12:in `run'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/lib/astrails/safe.rb:53:in `safe'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/lib/astrails/safe/config/node.rb:51:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/lib/astrails/safe/config/node.rb:51:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/lib/astrails/safe.rb:52:in `safe'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/lib/astrails/safe.rb:46:in `each'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/lib/astrails/safe.rb:46:in `safe'
    from /Users/phyowaiwin/sites/web_apps/myapp/trunk/lib/backup/local.rb:1
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/bin/astrails-safe:50:in `load'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/bin/astrails-safe:50:in `main'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/astrails-safe-0.2.7/bin/astrails-safe:53
    from /opt/local/bin/astrails-safe:19:in `load'
    from /opt/local/bin/astrails-safe:19
```

The code in local.rb is as follow.

```
safe do

  local do
    path "/backup/:kind"
  end


  s3 do
     key "mykey"
     secret "mysecret"
     bucket "myapp-local-backup"
     path ":kind/:id" # this is default
  end


  keep do
    local 100
    s3 100
    mysqldump 100
  end

  # backup mysql databases with mysqldump
  mysqldump do
    # you can override any setting from parent in a child:
    options "-ceKq --single-transaction --create-options"

    user "root"
    password ""
    # host "localhost"
    # port 3306
    socket "/tmp/mysql.sock"
    database :myapp_development


  end

  tar do
    options "-h" # uncomment this to dereference symbolic links

    archive "myapp-local-com" do
      files "~/sites/web_apps/myapp/branches"
    end

  end



end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about the plugin, but someone who does would find it extremely helpful to have the code where you use the plugin, and a more detailed backtrace :)

Comment: I've now added the code I run and the error I got there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but creating the bucket with the option "Place this bucket in Europe" is causing this error, it seems. When I create a new bucket without that option it works fine now.

I am using S3 Firefox Organiser plugin/addon to add the buckets, by the way.

Hope this helps with people with same issue too.

Cheers.

Comment: This solved the problem for me.  I was using the .NET c# example code with the SDK download (the s3 Transfer Utility Sample).  I originally created the bucket in Europe, and I got the "Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it".  I deleted the bucket, recreated it in US Standard and the utility worked fine.